# userscript doesn't work on yammer.com

Tags: userscripts, yammer, tampermonkey

If you joined more than a few groups in yammer.com, then the left side bar which showing groups will have a link "View all your groups". You need to click this link to show all of your joined groups.

Most of time I want to see the full list of joined groups to check new posts. So I ended up click that link many times when I visit yammer.com. So I was trying to automate this using writing tampermonkey script do do this for me.

```
function expandall(jNode)
{
    console.log('click expand all');
    jNode.click();
}
waitForKeyElements('a.yj-nav-menu--group-item-link.yj-nav-menu--show-all-groups-link', expandall);
```

I can see that the function was triggered since it does output "click expand all" in console, however looks like it doesn't trigger the click on that link, the groups in the left side of page doesn't expand.

Anything wrong with the userscript above?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try `jNode.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));`. Any added event listener should receive that.

Comment: Did you check that jNode is indeed the node you want to click?

Comment: I changed to wait another element (<span> insider <a>) and it worked. Thanks.